# Why did God give man an imagination?

Tags: biblical-basis, creation

This is a two-part question.

First: Throughout the Old Testament we read of the “imagination of the heart” and in Genesis 6:5 “imagination of the thoughts of the heart”.

In an earlier question “curiosity” was singled out and I wonder if there are any historical Church teachings that link the imagination of the heart with Holy curiosity?

Secondly: Are their any Christian teachings as to why God gave man an imagination?

Comment: Most of the biblical statements about the imagination are negative, however it would seem that if the imagination was held captive by Christ to the "truth" then it would be a critical component in our faith and understanding God.

Comment: Isn't imagination necessary for freewill?

Comment: Certainly that Makes sense to me!

Comment: My guess is that it is similar to the creativity that God possesses; though I would not say He is imaginative, being omniscient, I would say that imagination in humans allows us to be creative like God and build amazing things.

Comment: Perhaps it is so we can imagine Him?

Comment: http://www.peterkreeft.com/audio/22_cslewis_imagination.htm

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open because it is interesting and close enough to site scope to let it slide in my opinion.

Comment: I'm still voting to leave it open (because it's sitting in the close review queue again). Perhaps, Rick, there is some way you can adjust the wording so this doesn't happen again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the [motivation of God](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3983/20).

Comment: If this wasn't a divine motivations question it would be a verse search question. Neither are constructive.

Answer (score 1):

A key verse in regard to the imagination is 2 Corinthians 10:5”:

> “Casting down imaginations, and every high thing that exalteth itself against the knowledge of God, and bringing into captivity every thought to the obedience of Christ”

The imagination allows us to see what is physically unseeable.  The imagination is to be given to truth (Christ) not to the Father of lies (Satan).

> Mark 8:17,18 …have ye your heart yet hardened? Having eyes, see ye not? and having ears, hear ye not? and do ye not remember?

In contrast the imagination has been so overrun with un-truth that we associate the imagination with fiction.  We tell our children “you were just imagining that” and believe an overactive imagination is to blame.  God equipped man with an imagination so that man might be able to see things of eternal substance, in order to comprehend His eternal reality.

The truth in our imaginations are critical to our relationship with God; the problem is our imaginations have become slums neglected and ignored because we have convinced ourselves that it is the residence of superstition.

Most of the soul’s battlefield is within the imagination of the heart.

> 1 Chronicles 29:18 “O LORD God of Abraham, Isaac, and of Israel, our fathers, keep this for ever in the imagination of the thoughts of the heart of thy people, and prepare their heart unto thee”